# Git Bash Script Check Working Tree

Tags: bash, git-bash

Is there a way in Git Bash to check if the working tree is clean, that is no uncommitted changes or untracked files?

I'm working on a bash script for my group to automate the process of daily rebasing working branches.  Unclean working trees is a common problem.  I can manually correct the problem by executing `git checkout .`.  This would have the desired result most of the time, but not always, so I need to be able to have my script programatically check that the working directory/tree is clean.

Comment: `git help clean` may be of interest.

Comment: "git status" might be useful, too.

Comment: `git status` (specifically the `--porcelain` option for machine parsing) can give you this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`git-sh-setup`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-sh-setup.sh) script included with git contains a number of useful functions for working with git repositories. Among them is [`require_clean_work_tree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-sh-setup.sh#L202):

```
require_clean_work_tree () {
    git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null || exit 1
    git update-index -q --ignore-submodules --refresh
    err=0
    if ! git diff-files --quiet --ignore-submodules
    then
        echo >&2 "Cannot $1: You have unstaged changes."
        err=1
    fi
    if ! git diff-index --cached --quiet --ignore-submodules HEAD --
    then
        if [ $err = 0 ]
        then
            echo >&2 "Cannot $1: Your index contains uncommitted changes."
        else
            echo >&2 "Additionally, your index contains uncommitted changes."
        fi
        err=1
    fi
    if [ $err = 1 ]
    then
        test -n "$2" && echo >&2 "$2"
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

This is in addition to being able to check the output from `git status --porcelain` and/or `git status -z` if you need to be more specific about what the state currently is.